# AngularJS: How to test Factories

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, factory

I have a `session.factory.js` factory:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('Session', Session);

    function Session() {
        var sessionId;

        return {
            create: create,
            destroy: destroy,
            isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated
        };

        function create(id) {
            sessionId = id
        }

        function destroy() {
            sessionId = null;
        }

        function isAuthenticated() {
            return !!sessionId;
        }
    }
})();
```

And I want to test it, so I've made a `session.factory.spec.js`:

```
describe('Session', function() {
    var Session;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('app');

        inject(function(_Session_){
            Session = _Session_;
        });
    });
});
```

But `Session` is `undefined` for some reason. What I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to load in your module like this:

```
describe('Session', function() {
    var Session;

    beforeEach(module('app'));  //added

    beforeEach(inject(function(_Session_){
            Session = _Session_;
    });
});
```

`module('app')` returns a function that is then invoked by before each.  The way you have it in the OP, the function is created by never invoked.

`inject` is the same.  It should sit inside the `beforeEach` directly.

**EDIT:**

The above code is the *usual* way to do it, but it turns out you can also define the `module` and `inject` functions in the way the OP is doing.

After [building a plunker for this question](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ma1xe450K9rTzglO340y?p=preview), I can see that the problem was not in the definition of the test.  It was actually a problem with the way the module was defined.

This line:

```
angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('Session', Session);
```

Should have been this:

```
angular
        .module('app', [])
        .factory('Session', Session);
```

The `[]` is important because it signifies that this is the *root* module (or app).  Without this, the module will be treated as a dependent module and not be created correctly.

Comment: I made another edit.  `inject` is the same.  It returns a function.  So, there is no need to wrap in another function inside the `beforeEach`.

Comment: Ok, now it's working, just an edit: 
```beforeEach(inject(function(_Session_){
            Session = _Session_;
    }));```

Comment: You dont need those `()` invocations

Comment: @PSL I think you do because both `module` and `inject` are factories that return functions. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @PSL after creating a plunker, I do see an error.  So, my bad. :)  I've made an edit.

Comment: @MatheusLima I've made and edit and included a working plunker.